# Google Tag Manager security breach?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Anyone else experiencing problems with google tag manager?
Our work account has deleted container-permissions without a user defined doing it. We heard some other accounts also have problems? Anyone who knows whats going on? No email accounts have been compromised.

[image: permission deletes without user who did it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been acknowledged. There are problems rising everywhere.

[image: TAG MANAGER BUG/HACK]

[Google Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/gPFJsuM0Tnw;context-place=forum/tag-manager)

[Latest news about the bug, google says everything will be restored](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=18&iid=bfc3fd8b6dcf2e4a1515f2c208bbdab2)

- Tracking starts working again, only problem left is access to the containers using the User Interface, Google is working on it.
- UI Back ! Everything working again, my changes of the last day are gone.

Answer (score 1):

if your container is still working - back it up ASAP! There is not guarantee that Google will be able to restore it, Nobody knows why this is happening as of now

Comment: Google Confirmed it can be restored, even better everything starts working again, except for UI access at the moment of speaking :)